# Facebook Login with another account from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm developing an iOS app that integrates with Facebook SDK. When I make the login for the first time with my facebook account it takes the following steps:

1. Jump to safari web login
2. Insert my credentials
3. After that I authorize the permissions that are requested
4. And then I go to the main menu of my application.

When I press the logout button, I run the following code:

```
- (void)logout {
     [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

With this code I can invalidate the session and clear the access token information. However, when i try to login again, my application jumps to safari web login and my account appears already as logged in (next picture).

[image: Already logged in!]

If I want to login with another Facebook account, i can't do it. In other words, I would like to follow the steps that I said earlier or have a mechanism like "Not you?" that Facebook official app provides.

Any idea that what I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're still logged in through Safari. Log out there (or clear your cache).

Answer (score 1):

wrong, happens when not logged in safari and FB app.

Comment: Please expand your answer to make it clear in what way you provide an answer.